# Qt TableView - How to show image, when mouse hover?

Tags: image, qt, tableview

I've got table view that is reading from SQL Database in one of my Qt project. It contains names column, and column that store the path of some image. How i can show the image like a ToolTip, when i do hover with the mouse on some of the image paths? I 've activated the mouse tracking, but i really don't know how to use it. If you can please provide some example. Than you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The view's model should respond to `Qt::TooltipRole` and return the tooltip's content. It can contain HTML tags, including `img` tag that displays an image:

```
class Model : public QAbstractTableModel {
public:
  //...
QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {
  if (role == Qt::ToolTipRole) {
    // find path for specified index
    return QString("<img src='%1'>").arg(path);
  }
  //...
}
```

If you're using a built-in model class such as `QSqlRelationalTableModel`, you can create a subclass of that class and reimplement `data` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Pavel Strakhov. Finally i've solved my problem. I've used some fragment from your principe and other fragment of code from other forum. Now everything works fine. Thanks again.